# Can Not Get Shared Folder Original (System Path)

Tags: c#

Get Shared Folder System Path But Code 
Return same Path Shared Folder Like '@\123.1.1.56\Pagal'

```
DirSearch("\\\\DESKTOP-2FFGFDM\\Packages");

static void DirSearch(string dir, string rootDir = null)
{

    if (rootDir == null)
    {
        rootDir = dir;
    }
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
        {
            string filename = f.Substring(rootDir.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(filename);
        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
            DirSearch(d, rootDir);
        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I can Not Find Shared Folder System Path 
So Pls. Help me.........
Thanks In Advance

Comment: `@\123.1.1.56\Pagal` is not a valid path (shared or not) and the code doesn't show any attempt to find a path, it seems to search for files recursively. Why don't you just use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` or GetFIles with the [AllDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=netframework-4.8) option?

Comment: I'm failing to see a need for dir and rootDir, just pass the directory you need. alsp perhaps consider using a DirectoryInfo you can test to see if the directory exists. as mentioned by Panagiotis, a unc path would be \\123.1.1.56, you are missing a \

Comment: One reason for this code may be to avoid exceptions caused by inaccessible files or folders. In .NET Core 2.1 and later you can use [EnumerateOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=netcore-2.1) with GetFile and set the [IgnoreInaccessible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions.ignoreinaccessible?view=netcore-2.1#System_IO_EnumerationOptions_IgnoreInaccessible) flag

Comment: But I Pass In  dir=\\Server\Shared Folder     And I Get System Path Of This Shared Folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a network share exists you can use a DirectoryInfo

```
static void DirSearch(string dir, string rootDir = null)
{
    if(!new DirectoryInfo(dir).Exists)
      throw new Exception($"the provided directory {dir} is not valid.")

    if (rootDir == null)
    {
        rootDir = dir;
    }
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
        {
            string filename = f.Substring(rootDir.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(filename);
        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
            DirSearch(d, rootDir);
        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

if this is a school assignment for recursive programming than that would work, however you can just get all files and [directory without the recursion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
     string filename = f.Substring(rootDir.Length);
     Console.WriteLine(filename);
}
```

as these files come from directories you can get those out of the name

```
var dir="";
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string filename = f.Substring(rootDir.Length);
    var directoryName = new FileInfo(filename).Directory.FullName;
    if(directoryName!=dir)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(filename);
      dir= directoryName ;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(filename);
}
```